# Two one-to-many relationship with abstract class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure whether or not my logic and implementation is correct and won't have any issues. The potential problem is the following: I have an abstract class, `Classifier`, which has two concrete classes: `ToolClassifier` and `ManualClassifier`:

```
[Table("Classifiers")] //TPT Inheritance
public abstract class Classifier
{
    [Column(name: "classifier_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(name: "date_added")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClassifierVulnWeight> ClassifierVulnWeight { get; set; } = null!;
}

[Table("ToolClassifiers")] //TPT Inheritance
public class ToolClassifier : Classifier
{
    [Column(name: "tool_name")]
    public string ToolName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "tool_acronym")]
    public string ToolAcronym { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "tool_url")]
    public string ToolURL { get; set; } = null!;

}

[Table("ManualClassifiers")] //TPT Inheritance
public class ManualClassifier : Classifier
{
    [Column(name: "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "label_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "passwordHash")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "passwordSalt")]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

The `Classifier` establishes a one-to-many relationship with the class `ClassifierVulnWeight`. The `VulnerabilityClass` also establishes a one-to-many relationship with the class `ClassifierVulnWeight`:

```
public class ClassifierVulnWeight
{
    [Column(name: "classifier_id")]
    public int ClassifierId { get; set; }
    public Classifier Classifier { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column(name: "vuln_class_id")]
    public int VulnerabilityClassId { get; set; }
    public VulnerabilityClass VulnerabilityClass { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column(name: "last_update")]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    [Column(name: "weight")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }        
}

 public class VulnerabilityClass
{
    [Column(name: "vuln_class_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(name: "vuln_class_name")]
    public string VulnerabilityClassName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(name: "vuln_class_acronym")]
    public string VulnerabilityClassAcronym { get; set; } = null!;
    public ICollection<ClassifierVulnWeight> ClassifierVulnWeight { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

The `ClassifierVulnWight` has a composite primary key, composed of the classifier Id and VulnClass Id, as shown below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassifierVulnWeight>()
            .HasKey(classifierVulnWeight => new
            {
                classifierVulnWeight.ClassifierId,
                classifierVulnWeight.VulnerabilityClassId
            });
```

My question is the following: will I have any troubles when creating instances of `ClassifierVulnWeight` since I have the abstract class `Classifier`? This is because the obligation is in the Tool Classifier and Manual Classifier entities, i.e., there is no Classifier instance unless there is at least an instance of one of the two aforementioned.
I'm guessing that the ICollection property in the Classifier instance is inherited by both children and thus there will be no problem. Is my assumption correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think TPH mapping is more applicable to your entities, since there's a type hierarchy: classes `ToolClassifier` and `ManualClassifier` inherit from `Classifier`. They can be mapped to one table `Classifiers`.

Comment: That is true, but for a better organization and fewer NULL values in a single table (as in the case of TPH) I went with the TPT approach although I can easily change that. And referring to the question in this post, will the abstract class influence or have any issues in terms of the relationship of one-to-many (with ClassifierVulnWeight class)?